# Magento: Create custom admin login from

Tags: magento-1.8, php, forms

i created some admin users with limited user roles, i want to create a custom login form, so that after login, user will be re-directed to his admin home page.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? By default all the actions you assigned to the role of the users will only be available.

Comment: i have created a separated panel for user, say 'localhost/magento/user' where my custom login form will display and i will check the login credentials from the admin_user table and after login render to the admin page. thats it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use magento's default login function for backend.

```
Mage::getModel('admin/user')->authenticate($username, $password)
```

To be able to create a new login page you need to extend the original login function.
The class I think you need is this one:

```
Mage_Adminhtml_IndexController
```

Comment: Im already using this Mage::getModel('admin/user')->authenticate($username, $password) to authenticate username and password. but how about bypass the magento admin login form. after login take me to the admin panel.

Comment: Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action this is class that I am extending

Comment: i got this error Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Adminhtml_IndexController' not found in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/local/Edge/Vendor/controllers/IndexController.php on line 2
when i extend the Mage_Adminhtml_IndexController

Comment: You can find here how to override controllers: http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/